# How to create a new Views in .NET Core for a new Controller in VSCode?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have created a Controller name **VoucherController** and have created an action inside this controller name "**voucherview**". Now when when I am creating a View for this action name voucherview.cshtml inside Views>Voucher>**voucherview.cshtml** it is giving me an error saying "The name 'View' does not exist for the current context". 
Also I tried finding "Add View" option but it is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your controller inherits the `controller` class and change your controller code to the following:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication_core.Controllers
{
    public class VoucherController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult voucherview()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Then right click on the voucherview action and the `Add View` option will appear.